# How to open the terminal in ubuntu

Tags: command-line

I am trying to correct my boot up to black screen but don't know how to get to the command prompt.  Environment is Ubuntu server 12.04

Here is a line of code that was given to me in an answer.

pkexec gedit /etc/default/grub

Sorry I'm so lame but at least I was able to stand up my server to black screen.
My NETGEAR Genie shows my box on the network map.  Not too bad for a beginner I spose.
Thanks for all your help folks.

Kenny

Comment: **Ctrl+Alt+F2** should do it.

Comment: yes, those keys will do, but without a graphical interface (X) you will need to use `sudo -e /etc/default/grub`.

Answer (score 0):

Good evening. Maybe you have a problem of brightness so you can test it by increasing the brightniess whith you keyboard shorcut for it (Fn + F3 for me).

Comment: I was finally able to get to the command-line and actually started to use a few commands.  Thank you for your kind responce.  So far, so good.